# move a horizontal line to the center in StyledSheets

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have drawn a horizontal line like this. However, it appears towards the left side of the screen. I don't want to increase the width. How else can I move it to the center? I tried wrapping it with another view along with alignContent: 'center' etc but it didn't work for me.

```
<View style={styles.horizontalLine}></View>
```

```
  horizontalLine: {
    marginTop: 25,
    width: '80%',
    height: 1,
    //alignContent: 'center',
    //width: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#E0E0E0',
  },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an alignSelf:'center' like below

```
 horizontalLine: {
    marginTop: 25,
    width: '80%',
    height: 1,
    //alignContent: 'center',
    //width: 1,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#E0E0E0',
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give horizontal margin: auto

```js
horizontalLine: {
  // ...
  marginLeft: 'auto',
  marginRight: 'auto',
  // ...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

`horizontalLine: {
    margin: 'auto',
    marginTop: 25,
    width: '80%',
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#E0E0E0',
}`